# phalcon my user creation form not working well with my database

Tags: php, database, forms, model-view-controller, phalcon

I am new on phalcon and i'm having a really weird problem here's a better explanation

- I have a form supposed to create a user
- My controller receive everything from my form
- A user is created in my database but only the email is registered

[form validation picture with var dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmyvI.png)

[database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlIAx.png)

here is my controller :

```
/**
 * Creates a new user
 */
public function createAction()
{
    if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
        $this->dispatcher->forward([
            'controller' => "users",
            'action' => 'index'
        ]);

        return;
    }

    $user = new Users();
    $user->setlastName($this->request->getPost("LastName"));
    $user->setfirstName($this->request->getPost("FirstName"));
    $user->setlogin($this->request->getPost("Login"));
    $user->setpassword($this->request->getPost("password"));
    $user->seteMail($this->request->getPost("eMail"));

    var_dump($this->request->getPost("LastName"));
    var_dump($this->request->getPost("FirstName"));
    var_dump($this->request->getPost("Login"));
    var_dump($this->request->getPost("Password"));
    var_dump($this->request->getPost("eMail"));

    var_dump($user);


    if (!$user->save()) {
        foreach ($user->getMessages() as $message) {
            $this->flash->error($message);
            var_dump($message);
        }

        $this->dispatcher->forward([
            'controller' => "users",
            'action' => 'new'
        ]);

        return;
    }

    $this->flash->success("user was created successfully");

    $this->dispatcher->forward([
        'controller' => "users",
        'action' => 'index'
    ]);
}
```

and my form :

```
<?php
        echo $this->tag->form(
            [
                "users/create",
                "class" => "form-horizontal"
            ]
        );
    ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fieldLastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">LastName</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <?php echo $this->tag->textField(["LastName", "cols" => 30, "rows" => 4, "class" => "form-control", "id" => "fieldLastname"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fieldFirstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">FirstName</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <?php echo $this->tag->textField(["FirstName", "cols" => 30, "rows" => 4, "class" => "form-control", "id" => "fieldFirstname"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fieldLogin" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Login</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <?php echo $this->tag->textField(["Login", "size" => 30, "class" => "form-control", "id" => "fieldLogin"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fieldPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <?php echo $this->tag->passwordField(["Password", "size" => 30, "class" => "form-control", "id" => "fieldPassword"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fieldEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">EMail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <?php echo $this->tag->textField(["eMail", "size" => 30, "class" => "form-control", "id" => "fieldEmail"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <?php echo $this->tag->submitButton(["Save", "class" => "btn btn-default"]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->tag->endForm(); ?>
```

here is the Users class :

```
<?php

namespace Phalcon_Punch;

class Users extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

/**
 *
 * @var integer
 */
protected $iD;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $lastName;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $firstName;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $login;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $password;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $grants;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $status;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $lastUpdateDate;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $eMail;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $tag;

/**
 * Method to set the value of field ID
 *
 * @param integer $iD
 * @return $this
 */
public function setID($iD)
{
    $this->iD = $iD;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field LastName
 *
 * @param string $lastName
 * @return $this
 */
public function setLastName($lastName)
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field FirstName
 *
 * @param string $firstName
 * @return $this
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field Login
 *
 * @param string $login
 * @return $this
 */
public function setLogin($login)
{
    $this->login = $login;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field Password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return $this
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field Grants
 *
 * @param string $grants
 * @return $this
 */
public function setGrants($grants)
{
    $this->grants = $grants;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field Status
 *
 * @param string $status
 * @return $this
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field LastUpdateDate
 *
 * @param string $lastUpdateDate
 * @return $this
 */
public function setLastUpdateDate($lastUpdateDate)
{
    $this->lastUpdateDate = $lastUpdateDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field eMail
 *
 * @param string $eMail
 * @return $this
 */
public function setEMail($eMail)
{
    $this->eMail = $eMail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Method to set the value of field tag
 *
 * @param string $tag
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTag($tag)
{
    $this->tag = $tag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field iD
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getID()
{
    return $this->iD;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field lastName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field firstName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field login
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLogin()
{
    return $this->login;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field password
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field grants
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGrants()
{
    return $this->grants;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field status
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field lastUpdateDate
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastUpdateDate()
{
    return $this->lastUpdateDate;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field eMail
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEMail()
{
    return $this->eMail;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of field tag
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTag()
{
    return $this->tag;
}

/**
 * Initialize method for model.
 */
public function initialize()
{
    $this->setSchema("basephalcon");
    $this->setSource("users");
}

/**
 * Returns table name mapped in the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSource()
{
    return 'users';
}

/**
 * Allows to query a set of records that match the specified conditions
 *
 * @param mixed $parameters
 * @return Users[]|Users|\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultSetInterface
 */
public static function find($parameters = null)
{
    return parent::find($parameters);
}

/**
 * Allows to query the first record that match the specified conditions
 *
 * @param mixed $parameters
 * @return Users|\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultInterface
 */
public static function findFirst($parameters = null)
{
    return parent::findFirst($parameters);
}
}
```

Comment: you've shown us the code which you've already proved is working (by doing var_dump()). So it seems likely the issue is somewhere within the "save" method of your user class. Unfortunately, you didn't show us that, so it's very hard to help you. Please edit your question with further info. (The HTML form is largely irrelevant actually, since you can prove that the data is being sent successfully)

Comment: @ADyson done but the save() method is sopposed to come from Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria i think

Comment: Ok but don't assume we all know this specific framework or what the code does. You can find the source code for it easily. It seems you're extending the `\Phalcon\Mvc\Model` class, so I'd expect the method is in there (or in a class which that class itself inherits).

Comment: Since you're extending it to include some custom fields, I'm not really clear how you'd necessarily expect it to know how to write those into the database automatically in the right place? Does it use some kind of naming convention? If so then your problem might be that in the DB, you have e.g. "LastName" as a DB field name but "lastName" as a PHP field name, so maybe it's case-sensitive. Just a guess, without seeing the actual code.

Comment: you were right it was because of the uppercase in my db thanks a lot

Comment: @ADyson can you make an answer to the post so i can mark it as resolved pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that in the DB, you have e.g. "LastName" as a DB field name but "lastName" as a PHP field name. It seems your framework uses a naming convention to map the PHP field names to the database field names, and this convention is case-sensitive.

Therefore you need to rename either your database field name or your PHP field name so that they fully match.

Answer (score 0):

you can use columnMap() to establish the correspondence between the names in the table and model

```
 public function columnMap()
    {
        return array(
            'LastName' => 'lastName', 
        );
    }
```